# Can use Angular8 like AngularJS?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have to transform a site made from AngularJS to Angular8, however, the site used js files without using NPM. Is it possible to do the same thing with Angular8? That is to download the Angular8 files and not to use a Node server.

Comment: No, you can not use Angular8 Like AngularJS way. there is no similarity between AngularJS and Angular8

Comment: please make your question  more clear

Comment: @Taupeman AngularJS is an MVC base and Angular8 is a component base architect.

Comment: Then I have to use a Node server to use Angular8 ?

Comment: @Taupeman Yes, you need to install node for Angular8

Comment: And when I'm going to put it into production, a Node server will be needed for page generation ?

Comment: @Taupeman if you build angular you pretty much get some  files in dist folder  , which can be put into any server and serve these files like any normal website. but you need node server at the time of development to run or serve the app

Comment: @Taupeman When you go for production you need to the same installation, But in production there run Angular8 build.

Comment: You do not need a nodejs server to host an Angular 8 app. You do need nodejs to develop and build an Angular 8 APP.

Comment: Ok thanks you for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can not use `Angular8` Like `AngularJS` way. there is no similarity between AngularJS and Angular8.

AngularJS is an `MVC` base and Angular8 is a `component` base architect.

You need to Install Node for Angular8.

When you go for production you need to the same installation, But in production there run Angular8 build.